# Why does a while loop produce unlimited result when mysql is accessed from php class

Tags: php, class, mysqli

There is a class as defined below

```
class table {

    public $mysqli;
    public $display;

    public function mysqli() {
         $mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');
         return $mysqli;
    }

    public function __construct() {
         $this->mysqli = $this->mysqli();
    }

    public function display() {

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
         if($data = $this->mysqli->query($sql)) {
               $this->display = $data->fetch_assoc();
         };
    }
}

$table = new table();
$table->display();
while($table->display) {
    $this->display['name']. " " . $this->display['country'];
};
```

the public function `$this->display` was assigned a value a `$data->fetch_assoc()`. Indirectly, `while($table->display = $data->fetch_assoc())` is equivalent to `while($data->fetch_assoc()`. but the result does not loop through the list. Instead, it displays only the first row over and over again until system crashes.

Is there a rule guiding php class that i am not aware about or am i missing my commands?

Comment: _“the public function `$this->display`”_ - that is a _property_, not a _method_ _“was assigned a value”_ - exactly, _was_ - past tense. You are not updating this anywhere anymore afterwards.

Comment: That `while` loop isn't really doing anything. In any case, it's more idiomatic to use `foreach` instead of `while` when iterating over arrays.

Comment: @misorude. If using the class in the example above was neglected, instead of writing a query as `while($row = $display->fetch_assoc()) { // do this }`. will it be wrong to do something like this. `$row = $display->fetch_assoc(); while($row) { //do this }`. Because the second was the kind of attempt i was using.

Comment: Yes, of course that would be wrong, because the value of $row would never change after you initially assign the contents of the first row. And if $row never changes, then `while($row)` does not have a reason to ever _terminate_ either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer misorude. I guess that is where the problem actually is

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you supposed to make your loop like :

```
while($row = $table->display) {
    $row['name']. " " . $row['country'];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class table {

    public $mysqli;
    public $display;

    public function mysqli() {
         $mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database');
         return $mysqli;
    }

    public function __construct() {
         $this->mysqli = $this->mysqli();
    }

    public function display() {

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
         $this->display = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
    }
}

$table = new table();
$table->display();
while($row = $table->display->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row['name']. " " . $row['country'];
};
```